# Is there windows a utility that can write/read/create and manage image files like IMG, ISO, etc?

Tags: windows, disk-image, binary-files, img

I am wondering if there is a utility for windows that can write/read/create and manage image files?

E.G. Trying to write a custom bootsector for a floppy img file

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: PowerISO is a *POWERFUL* utility for managing disk images, but I needed to write a binary file compiled from nasm to an image file. So what I did was I made a blank "floppy image" by creating a blank text file, and changing it to a ".img" file. I opened Hex Edit (HxD) and opened both my floppy image and binary file, copied the contents of my binary file (HEX) and pasted it into the hex of the floppy image. If you want to have more space on your floppy, create a floppy image using power iso and paste (write) from the begining hex.

Its confusing so Ill make a program that inserts them

Comment: "What program is there to do...." belongs more on [softwarerecs.se] but you should include a lot more information. You should include information on the actual problem you are attempting to solve and all of the specific requirements. It can be helpful to read their [quality guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

One program from the early years that still is viable is [PowerISO](https://www.poweriso.com/tutorials/make-floppy-image.htm). It specifically manages .img files as well as ISO files, among others.

[image: poweriso menu image]

image courtesy of linked site.

I've used it in the distant past, not necessarily for floppy boots, but possibly, and the program is fairly intuitive to use.

It's a windows only program and requires purchase US$30.00, although the free version will allow up to 300 MB image files.

Comment: i have power iso but i dont know how to write my bin file too the boot sector. I tried using Tools/View / Edit sector data and copying the hex data of my bin but it resulted in an error.

Comment: and i mean bin as in binary files compiled from nasm